# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) console error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I have made an image slider and I have done everything so far but the problem is that slideshow does not even work because the main js script does not load. So I saw the Inspect and at the Console section I saw this error:

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) css/head.css**

I don't know why it shows me this cause I don't have *head.css* file at all! Here's my code:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<?php include_once 'php/includes/overall/head.php'; ?>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js">
        $(function(){
            $('.crsl-items').carousel({
                visible: 3,
                itemMinWidth: 180,
                itemEqualHeight: 370,
                itemMargin: 9,
            });
            $("a[href=#]").on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
        </script>
</head>
```

And *head.php* goes like this:

```
<!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>   
    <link type="text/css" href="css/head.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/slider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>  
    <link type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet"/>    
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/responsiveCarousel.min.js"></script>
```

For this slideshow I only need these two:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/responsiveCarousel.min.js"></script>
```

Which is included correctly... You can see the full site [here](http://gooyanet.com).

And here is the [image: print screen] of the slideshow that I'm talking about and how it should be in a correct way.

So if you know what's going wrong here please let me know ... thanks in advance.

Comment: Try deleting any script file that you are not using and any script call to a script that does not exist

Answer (score 0):

In your head.php file there is

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/head.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

?

Comment: No I just added it to see if the error is gone or not ... its empty however

Comment: The error does not show when I add this empty head.css file but it still does not work which means the main problem still remains

Comment: So when there is no <link type="text/css" href="css/head.css" rel="stylesheet"/> in the head.php file, it is still giving the error?